# Pandigital mobile number probability proof verification

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Recently I decided to get a mobile number that is pandigital (and I got one, but that is beside the point). I have been really interested in the probability that a randomly selected mobile number from this particular mobile carrrier is indeed a pandigital number without redundant digits.

Now, if we ignore the country calling code that goes in front of the mobile number (which is 7 in my case, but that is again beside the point), the rest of the mobile number consists of 10 digits (at least here in Russia). This is perfect, as there are 10 digits in the decimal system too.

My mobile carrier's mobile numbers always begin with three fixed digits (call them "prefixes"), here they are (there are $12$ of them): 903, 905, 906, 909, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969.

There are 3 prefixes that don't allow for a pandigital number to form (these are the 909, 966 and 969), which means we can "discard" them. For the $9$ remaining prefixes, the number of endings formed with them (such that the whole number ends up being pandigital) is : $7!*9$.

However, there are $12*10^7$ mobile numbers in total (including the ones with the defective prefixes).

It follows that the probability that a given mobile number from this particular carrier is pandigital is:

$\frac{7!*9}{12*10^7}=0.0378$% (exactly)

Of course this is all true only if each of the remaining $7$ digits of the mobile number are genuinely random.

**Now, I want to know if my probability theory reasoning is correct or not.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, under the assumptions you state, the calculation is correct.  It is likely that the carrier assigns numbers in some way that is not random.  Perhaps some of the prefixes are more likely than others.  Perhaps they save "nice" numbers, like those with all digits the same or those ending with lots of zeros, to sell at a higher price to people who want them.  The second will not involve many numbers out of the pool, so will not change things much.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you and think there _is_ something going on "behind the curtains". Still, I am pretty excited that the property my mobile number has is so extremely hard to come by.